# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse error Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I"m getting the _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) error when I'm trying to delete a pointer memory. I've checked else where in the code and doesn't seem like I'm double deleting.

Can anyone please guide..

```
enum SHAPE_TYPES {RECTANGLE, TRIANGLE, CIRCLE};
map<SHAPE_TYPES,vector<Shape *>> shapeMap;

vector<Shape *>rectVector;
shapeMap.insert(pair<SHAPE_TYPES, vector<Shape*>>(RECTANGLE,rectVector));


map<SHAPE_TYPES,vector<Shape *>>::iterator mapIter;
mapIter = shapeMap.find(RECTANGLE);
        if (mapIter != shapeMap.end())
        {
            // create the shape
            RandomAttributes(R[shapes]);  
             // the key was found, so add data 
            shapePtr = R;
            mapIter->second.push_back(shapePtr);
        }
```

later on

```
map<SHAPE_TYPES,vector<Shape *>>::iterator mapIter;
mapIter = shapeMap.find(RECTANGLE);
        if (mapIter != shapeMap.end())
        {
             if ( !mapIter->second.empty() )
              {
                    mapIter->second.back()->Draw();

                  delete mapIter->second.back();  // -- error causing line
                  mapIter->second.pop_back();
                 }
            }
```

Comment: What is `R`? What is `shapes`? What does `RandomAttributes` do? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: R is object of a class Rectangle. shapes is just a  counter in a for loop which I've not put over here. It basically loops equal to the number of elements which I inserted into the vector inside map. RandomAttributes assigns some features to another object of different class. 

I don't think any of that has really anything to do with deleting the pointer. I've checked, there is no destructor deleting data anywhere.

Comment: What we really need to know is how you *declare* and *initialize* `R`. Is it an array? Do you allocate dynamically?

Comment: MyRect R[NUM_SHAPES];   // NUM_SHAPES is somewhat the shapes counter i told earlier.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least one, maybe two (or more) problems with your code.

The first problem is that `R` is an *array*, and arrays are allocated by the compiler statically at the time of compilation. You should not `delete` it. Only `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. And why have an old C-style array to begin with, if you use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and you can use simple assignment and the array (or vector) will be copied.

There is another possible problem, if your array is defined locally in a function, and you then use the pointer to it in another function. This is because local variables are *local* to the function (or block inside the function) it's defined in. Once the code leaves the block the local variable is defined in then the it's destructed, and if you have a pointer to it the pointer becomes stray and points to no-longer existing data, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you use it.

Comment: I don't thing the function scope is the problem because both are in the main. Maybe something to do with the way I'm deleting. Regarding deleting...if we do only delete arr, it deleted the specific element, however if I do delete[] it would delete the entire thing. So isn't using only delete correct? I tried this also delete[] mapIter->second.back();

Comment: @rSU Read the second paragraph of my answer again, especially the first two sentences of that paragraph.

Comment: Oh my bad. But I still don't use the pointer to it from another function. Everything is being done in the main.

Comment: @rSU As long as everything is in `main` and `R` is not in a sub-block (inside an `if`/`while`/`for`/etc) then that's okay, and that issue is unrelated to the one you're asking about. You just can't free things you don't allocate.